# Why do we need sulfuric acid in reducing nitric acid?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, redox

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II)_sulfate):

> [image]

Why do we need sulfuric acid in the left part of the formula? Wouldn't FeSO4 reduce nitric acid without the sulfuric acid taking part?

---

P.S.

I was [answered](http://forum.xumuk.ru/index.php?showtopic=190955&p=996537) that a milder form of the reduction would still take place:

> [image]

Is that right?

So we need the acid to make the reduction more advanced, all the way to N(2+) from N(5+)? How does it work?

Comment: Sounds about right. Now, this is essentially the same reaction, but with different consequences. If you have excess $\ce{HNO3}$, it will (sort of) bring your $\ce{NO}$ back to $\ce{NO2}$. If you don't, it won't.